# Geth does not really attach

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

A question about `geth attach`. I am opening a `geth console` and then in another terminal I make `geth attach`. Everything looks OK when I execute `web3` commands etc. (like `eth.accounts`) in both terminals. Then, I deploy a contract through the console (1st terminal) using `loadScript()`, and as usual it is successfully mined as I see from the console messages. However, after that moment, when I want to use the deployed contract through the attached console (2nd terminal), I am unable to do it. It does not event see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The different terminals only share the same backend node- all the JS variables are local to the specific console you are using

Comment: But when we deploy a contract, isn't it added to the blockchain which in my logic should be accessable via all the terminals?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the contract deployed through `terminal 1` is only local scope. To get it in `terminal 2` you have to `invoke` the contract by address/api and perform functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let terminal 2 know where the contract is and what it's ABI is.

```
myContract = eth.contract(ABI).at(address)
```